# Using Web Services with EF Code First approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-services, wcf, ef-code-first

I have developed some **MVC** applications by using **Entity Framework code first** approach and now I am developing a new application that will also use **web services** for mobile applications that we will create. So, I have trouble about the issues below. Could you clarify me please one by one regarding to the issues?

1. Which web service technology should I use i.e. Web API, WCF, etc? (I am using MVC5 and EF version 6 in my project)
2. Can I use **the same** CRUD methods for my web application and for web services? If so, which modifications should be made on the methods and on the other fields i.e. models, etc?
3. For a current MVC application where EF code first approach was used, is it better to create a new methods for web services or should the current methods be updated by adding ability to support also web services?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-1

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks for reply. But it is limited and seems to be for Azure. I think it is better to use Web API instead of WCF as we use this web services for sharing data with our mobile applications. So, could you clarify me about the issues I asked on the question?

Comment: OK, here's a different tutorial (http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/261/integrating-web-api-with-asp-net-razor-web-pages) - there are tons of them out there with many options depending on your needs. Regarding 1, here is a simple comparison matrix. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks a lot for these useful links. Is the procedures in the article the same as WebAPI2? On the other hand, are they enough, or do you suggest to use OData endpoints with WebAPI? For the last problem, I think using WebAPI methods in the controller classes with both on web and on services is not possible. So, we need to create a method for web and another method for web services on different controllers. Is that true?

Comment: Well, many ways to go and still minimize redundancy. I'm starting a new project and plan on going with Web API 2 and angular for the front end.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers (**voted+**). Finally I decide to integrate WebAPI 2 with my MVC5 project as on [Integrating ASP.NET Web Forms, MVC and Web API](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/whats-new-in-visual-studio-2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms,-mvc-and-web-api). On the other hand, keeping in mind **security** and **maintennace concerns**, would you create a seperate project for WebAPI or would you use it on the same MVC project's UI layer (presentation layer)?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to use Commands and Queries. It's covered in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150321022633/https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150321004124/https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) articles.

The Command is simple DTO object, and it could be easily sent over the network. In this case you have control over the fields and behaviour you want to make public.

> Because commands are simple data containers without behavior, it is
>   very easy to serialize them (using the XmlSerializer for instance) or
>   send them over the wire (using WCF for instance), which makes it not
>   only easy to queue them for later processing, but ot also makes it
>   very easy to log them in an audit trail- yet another reason to
>   separate data and behavior. All these features can be added, without
>   changing a single line of code in the application (except perhaps a
>   line at the start-up of the application).

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, I most commonly use use EF methods i.e. SaveChanges, etc. on the database layer. Is there a problem regarding to this point if I use these methods? On the other hand, as we will develop also mobile applications and use the web services on them, I think it is better to use Web API instead of WCF. What do you think? Could you clarify me about the points above one by one?

Comment: There is no problem, because you won't serialize and send your EF entities over the wire. They will remain private. If you're going to develop mobile applications, make sure to follow SOLID principles ("I" letter in your case). It means that you'll need separate interface/api for mobile apps. And Web API is a kind of new and more preferable version of WCF. So it's better to go with Web API from the beginning.

Comment: There are also some different approach when trying to use WebAPI 2 and I am really very confused regarding to this issues. For example: #1) I will use WebAPI2, but there is also an option using OData endpoints. I have a look at it, but I am not sure if it is worth to use it in WebAPI2. What do you suggest? #2) How to integrate WebAPI2 to my existing MVC project? Should I create a new project or can I integrate it by creating new controllers and changing some configurations i.e. routing? >>>

Comment: #3) As far as I know, using WebAPI methods in the controller classes with both on web and on services is not possible. So, we need to create a method for web and another method for web services on different controllers. Is that true?

Comment: Many thanks for your answers (**voted+**). Finally I decide to integrate WebAPI 2 with my MVC5 project as on [Integrating ASP.NET Web Forms, MVC and Web API](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/whats-new-in-visual-studio-2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms,-mvc-and-web-api). On the other hand, keeping in mind **security** and **maintennace concerns**, would you create a seperate project for WebAPI or would you use it on the same MVC project's UI layer (presentation layer)?